# What causes error "Strings cannot be added or subtracted in dialect 3"

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.1

I have the query:

```
WITH STAN_IND
AS (
SELECT ro.kod_stanow, ro.ind_wyrob||' - '||ro.LP_OPER INDEKS_OPERACJA, count(*) ILE_POWT
FROM M_REJ_OPERACJI ro
JOIN M_TABST st ON st.SYMBOL = ro.kod_stanow
WHERE (st.KOD_GRST starting with 'F' or (st.KOD_GRST starting with 'T')  )  AND ro.DATA_WYKON>'NOW'-100
GROUP BY 1,2)

SELECT S.kod_stanow, count(*) ILE_INDEKS, SUM(ILE_POWT-1) POWTORZEN
from STAN_IND S
GROUP BY S.kod_stanow
ORDER BY ILE_INDEKS
```

That should be working, but I get an error:

> SQL Error [335544606] [42000]: Dynamic SQL Error; expression evaluation not supported; Strings cannot be added or subtracted in dialect 3 [SQLState:42000, ISC error code:335544606]

I tried to cast it into bigger varchar but still no success. What is wrong here? Database is a Firebird 2.1

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that includes the DDL, test data and a full query to execute which produces the error. At first glance your query looks fine to me, but the error suggests that you're using `-` or `+` between strings, which doesn't seem to happen in the code shown (unless maybe this query is contained in a string literal and executed with `EXECUTE STATEMENT` from PSQL).

Comment: Your problem is probably `'NOW'-100`, but I can't verify that right now. Use `CAST('NOW' as TIMESTAMP) - 100` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 100` (or cast to `DATE` or use `CURRENT_DATE` if the column `DATA_WYKON` is a `DATE`). The literal `'NOW'` is not a date/timestamp by itself, only when compared to a date or timestamp column will it mean that, and here the subtraction happens before that point.

Comment: CAST('NOW' as TIMESTAMP) - 100
did the job, thank you

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I wrote an answer based on my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is `'NOW'-100`. The literal `'NOW'` is not a date/timestamp by itself, but a `CHAR(3)` literal. Only when compared to (or assigned to) a date or timestamp column will it be converted, and here the subtraction happens before that point. And the subtraction fails, because subtraction from a string literal is not defined.

Use `CAST('NOW' as TIMESTAMP) - 100` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 100` (or cast to `DATE` or use `CURRENT_DATE` if the column `DATA_WYKON` is a `DATE`).